# Spring Security: Execute jQuery Code Only For Authenticated Users

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm following a tutorial on building a website using Spring MVC with some basic Spring Security. I have the following issue:

**Functionality**

The jQuery in the home page sends a request to the `/getmessages` method which returns a JSON object representing a map. The 'size' property is the quantity of messages. jQuery then updates a SPAN tag with that value. This SPAN tag is contained within a `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` tag so only logged in users can see it. This is done on a loop every 5 seconds.

The `/getMessages` URL is protected by an `isAuthenticated()` intercept.

**Expected Behavior**

- The user clicks the "Log In" link on the home page, which brings the user to the login page
- The user successfully logs in and the user is redirected back to the home page.

**Actual Behavior**

- The user clicks the "Log In" link on the home page, which brings the user to the login page
- The user successfully logs in but the user is redirected to the `/getmessages` URL which displays the raw JSON data

I assume this is happening because the jQuery request to `/getmessages` is occurring regardless if the user is logged in or not. When the user does log in, Spring redirects to the most recent request attempt for a protected URL, in this case `/getmessages`.

**Question**

How do I achieve my expected behavior. Ideally, I would prefer jQuery not to call `/getmessages` if the user is not authenticated. I have tried surrounding that part of the jQuery in `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` which does work but I have no idea if including sec tags in jQuery/JavaScript code good/bad/ugly practice.

Another possibility is to return from the server to jQuery a variable that indicates if the user (principal) is logged in, and then use that in an IF statement to guard entry to the `/getmessages` call

I'd appreciate advice on the best way to approach this problem.

**Code**

Home Page jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function getMessageCount(data){

    $("#message-count").text(data.size);        

}

function onLoad(){

    updatePage();
    window.setInterval(updatePage, 5000);

}

function updatePage(){



    $.getJSON("<c:url value="/getmessages"/>", getMessageCount);



}



$(document).ready(onLoad);


</script>
```

getMessages Method

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getmessages", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
@ResponseBody
public Map<String, Object> getMessages(Principal principal){

    List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

    if(principal != null){  
        String username = principal.getName();          
        messages = userService.getMessages(username);           
    }

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("messages", messages);
    data.put("size", messages.size());

    return data;

}
```

Login Page JSP (Tile)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

      document.f.j_username.focus()

})


</script>

<h3>Login With Username and Password</h3>

<c:if test="${param.auth != null}">

    <p class="error">Username or password is incorrect</p>

</c:if>

<form name='f'
    action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check'
    method='POST'>

    <table class="formtable">
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" value=''></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" value=''></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Remember Me</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="_spring_security_remember_me"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="label"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value='Login'></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

</form>

<p>
    <a href="<c:url value='/newaccount' />">Create New Account</a>
</p>
```

Security Context Config XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">


<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, authority FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ?"
            users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, enabled FROM users WHERE BINARY username = ?" 
            id="jdbcUserService" />
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>


<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offerdeleted" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/getmessages" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/message" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/denied" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?auth=false" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/loggedout" />
    <security:access-denied-handler error-page="/denied" />
    <security:remember-me key="offersAppKey" user-service-ref="jdbcUserService" />
</security:http>


<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"></security:global-method-security>

<bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder">
</bean>
```

Comment: I don't think wrapping the part of JavaScript code in `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` is bad/ugly practice. Instead, blindly sending requests that need authentication doesn't feel good.

Comment: If you don't mind always redirecting to home page, maybe you want to try [always-use-default-target](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-form-target)

Comment: I second @qingbo. There is nothing wrong with using `sec:authorize` to change JavaScript logic. The second approach (setting a request in controller and evaluating it in JSP) is equally fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just secure the JavaScript code block that calls to the controller for fetching the JSON data with

```
<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
      Home Page jQuery script-block
</sec:authorize>
```

**Concern:** it is perfect to protect the code/section that a logged in user needs to see. You have rightly understood it that spring-security remembers to redirect that URL that is protected, onload you are calling that controller, just secure that, means the whole sequence of calling, i.e. the script block.

```
  $.getJSON("<c:url value="/getmessages"/>", getMessageCount);
```